# Managing references after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have an object, `Course`. Course has, as a property, a list of other courses that are pre-requisites:

```
public class Course
{
    public List<Course> Prereqs { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I create a list of courses in my application, and I serialize it. The list gets later loaded and deserialized.

Suppose I have two courses: Calculus 1 and Calculus 2. Calculus 1 has no pre-requisites, and Calculus 2 has Calculus 1 as a pre-requisite. My application creates a list called `Curriculum`: `List<Course> Curriculum = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Course>>(serializedList);`

Now, suppose I want to change the title of Calculus 1 from a "Calculus 1" to "Single Variable Calculus", (which is, let's pretend, the first element in the list):

```
Course Math101 = Curriculum[0];
Math101.CourseName = "Single Variable Calculus";
```

However, if I do: `Curriculum[1].Prerequisites[0].CourseName; \\ spit out the CourseName for Math101, as recorded as a pre-req for Math102` then I get "Calculus 1".

This is because when `Curriculum` is serialized, it serializes `Curriculum[0]` (Calc 1) and `Curriculum[1].Prerequisite[0]` (also Calc 1) separately.

**My question** Is there a easy way to manage serialization of what should be reference types using C# and JSON?

Comment: I think part of your problem is a confusion between courses (which have prereqs) and "enrollments", which have grades. An enrollment would be the record of a student being enrolled in a course during a term. It would have attributes like attendance, grades, maybe test scores, etc.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Honestly, that's not my confusion at all. This is a reduced example that is isomorphic to a much larger problem, given a context that is intended to be broadly familiar.

Comment: So, you're asking how to maintain object identity? Also, do you have any potential issues with circular or multiple references?

Comment: If the example of "grade" is insufficient, think of "CourseName" as the property instead.

Comment: You should specify which serialization technology you used which produced those results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to "preserve references in the object graph" across the serialization, then a tool (or manual process) that can encode the linking information must be used. [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) can indeed support this "by reference" serialization.

Basically, after the first time the encoder sees a *particular* object, it will emit a stub `$id` property with a distinct value (that is linked via `$ref`) in the resulting JSON. When Json.NET reads the JSON back in it will "re-reference" any such objects serialized like this.

See the [Preserving References](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) example.

Comment: @Arkamis I recommend trying to flatten/simplify the structure, if possible .. just because it's supported [in Json.NET] doesn't mean it should be used, although maybe this is one of those times. At least it's a different hammer. :)

Comment: I think this is not a terrible solution. The other solution is storing keys, and maintaining a separate list of courses, then I can always look up the course by key. However... doing this means that other things are a bit trickier.

Comment: Now, I need to figure out how to deserialize while both using a custom formatter and changing the settings >.<